# has_secure_password breaks unrelated attribute validation

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have a very similar issue than [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250907/has-secure-password-breaks-collection-save). I recently added `has_secure_password` to my User model. Everything is working great, except when I try to create a user from Facebook, which have a :friends attribute. In this case, i have this error when I try to `@user.save!`

```
> Validation failed: Friends is invalid
```

FB user creation was working perfectly before I added has_secure_password, and is still working when I save the users with `@user.save(validate: false)`

Once the user is already created and present in the database, the `@user.save!` method is working and the :friends are validated.

I also have a `validates :password, length:{minimum:8}, on: :create` in my User model, but the friends validation is still triggered even if I remove this line.

I could add a `has_facebook?` condition in my controller to completely skip any kind of validation when I try to create a user from FB, but I really want to understand why has_secure_password validation is triggered for something seemingly unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

The validation message sounds strange.
But in documentation you see, that has_secure_validation adds a presence validation on password on create. So I think you somehow overwrite that validation message.

To say something more concrete I would need to see more of your code.

So documentation sais:

> For further customizability, it is possible to supress the default validations by passing validations: false as an argument.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html

I would assume, you set validations to false and care yourself about them. So you can require password only, when it's not a facebook registration.